# python Firebase Cloud Storage - upload DataFrame without saving it

Tags: python, pandas, firebase

I want to save Dataframe without save it

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,storage
import pandas as pd

cred = credentials.Certificate("./s.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{'storageBucket':"s.appspot.com"})
#upload files
file_path = "./DataBase/tours.xlsx"
bucket = storage.bucket() # storage bucket
blob = bucket.blob(file_path)
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
blob.upload_from_filename(df)
```

let's say I have created DataFrame and I want to upload it without using ***df.to_excel()***
I have try use ***to_dict()*** and ***to_json()** but it doesn't work .

Any solve for this problem?

Comment: why are trying `blob.upload_from_filename()` if you don't have a file path for your df? how about `blob.upload_from_string(df.to_csv())` or `blob.upload_from_string(df.to_json())`?

Comment: it's just an example I have tried to_csv() and .to_json() but when I try to open the saved file I got this error ***Excel cannot open the file ‘tours2.xlsx' because the ﬁle format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the ﬁle has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the ﬁle.***

Comment: I don't know maybe may file XlSX, not CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to use for this.

First, instead of saving the excel file you just need to parse it as a Bytes array, then push the content of it to the Blob. Also, you need to use the df.to_excel() method because this includes a specific engine to create these types of files and upload them correctly to be readen.

The code would be like:

```
# Importing libraries and setting up the credentials and firebase app
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,storage
import pandas as pd
import io


cred = credentials.Certificate("./Keys/key.json") #Change for your key and bucket name
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{'storageBucket':"<<bucket-name>>.appspot.com"})

# Setting up the blob
bucket = storage.bucket() # storage bucket
blob = bucket.blob("example/example3.xlsx")
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

# Creating Bytes Output
output = io.BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)

# Writting to the Bytes Output

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
xlsx_data = output.getvalue()

# Upload the blob from the content of the byte.
blob.upload_from_string(xlsx_data)
```

I have tested it :) and excel reads correctly the file.